Setting up multitenancy for Power App application
I have an application created in Power App with a data source. How can I set up multi-tenancy so that I can share this application with other organizations, but so that they have their own set of data and properties.
Is this possible?
One approach I tried was to share the application with invited users from other organizations (tenants). But I'm not sure if this is the right solution.

Check this https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Governance-and/Multi-tenant-users-in-Power-Apps/td-p/966329 you need to invite other tenant users to your tenant where the app resides to share the application

Hi, thanks, yes I saw this solution but I don’t know if it is correct, if so then ok.


Note that: In Power Apps, if you want to share application to other tenant users then the only way is to add other tenant users as
guests in your Microsoft Entra ID tenant. Refer this
blog


There is no direct way to share an application from one tenant to another tenant.

Hence as a workaround, you need to invite other tenant users in your Microsoft Entra ID tenant:

And invite the user:

Once the user accepts the invite, the user will be added as guest in your tenant.

Make sure the guest user must be assigned Power Apps license.
Then share the app with the user. Refer this MsDoc

References:
Power Platform environments overview - Power Platform | Microsoft
Solved: Multi-tenancy in powerapps environments - Power Platform Community (microsoft.com)
